# Xstring package bug?

Tags: xstring, bugs

Why is `resultin` equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ (tokenized)? Shouldn't `result` and `resultin` be equal?

```latex
\documentclass{article}                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage{xstring}                    

\def\halo{%                             

    \verbtocs{\resultin} | \frac{1}{2} |
    ( result in function : \resultin )\\
}                                       

\begin{document}                        

    \halo                               
    \verbtocs{\result} | \frac{1}{2} |  
    ( result : \result )\\              

\end{document}
```

Comment: A character becomes a token the moment TeX sees it for the first time, and that doesn't (usually) change. When you made the definition of `\halo`, `\verb{1}{2}` got tokenized as `\verb` `{` `1` `}` `{` `2` `}`, and that was "frozen", so `\resultin` contains 7 tokens (`\verb`, `{`...) and `\result` contains 11 tokens (``\``, `v`, `e`...). That's the classical verb-command-in-argument issue :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik It's actually its less famous verb-command-in-macro-definition cousin :-P

Comment: are there any workarounds ? ;-)

Comment: @CarolLypher Certainly there are, but they all depend on what you are actually trying to do. For this simple case, one easy way out is to load the `cprotect` package and then do `\cprotect{\def\halo}{\verbtocs|blablabla|}`.

Comment: No “verbatim” command can go in the argument to another command; there are workarounds, such as `cprotect`, but you should explain what's your aim.

Comment: apart from the verb issue, never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph (latex does warn about that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another simple way, beside the suggestions in the comments, is to use the e-TeX primitive `\scantokens` around the verbatim code in your macro defintion:

```
\documentclass{article}                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage{xstring}                    

\def\halo{%                             
    \scantokens{%
        \verbtocs{\resultin} | \frac{1}{2} |
        ( result in function : \resultin )
    }%
}                                       

\begin{document}                        

    \halo                               

    \verbtocs{\result} | \frac{1}{2} |  
    ( result : \result )

\end{document}
```

outputs

> [image]

`\scantokens{...}` will process the code of its argument as if it was written to an external file and immediately read back from that file via `\input`. All catcodes, even the ones fixed after the macro body of `\halo` had been read, will be reassigned under the catcode regime active at the time `\scantokens` is executed.

*EDIT:* As pointed out in the comments, this method has some limitations on the text that can be used as verbatim material. You must be aware that TeX first scans the whole macro definition under the normal catcode regime and later reconsiders everything *it had successfully parsed ealier*. This for example explains the extra space in the output after `\frac`, because TeX had already tokenized it as macro name, which then got an extra space added after it in the `\scantokens` process.

Comment: Note, however, that the output isn't identical: the one with `\scantokens` contains a space-after-csname after `\frac`. The `\scantokens` version also can't have a `%` character, all `#` must be doubled, and all `{` and `}` must be balanced, and multiple sequential space (catcode 10) tokens are tokenized as a single space token. It's not prohibitive, but are the downside of using a verbatim command in an argument. There's not much to be done, really. This is not a criticism to the answer, just things to have in mind when using a verbatim macro in an argument.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Good point, I didn't even notice the extra space.